# Get date value based on month name

Tags: excel, date, format, excel-2011

The scenario I have is as follows:

- Cell A1 - contains the name of the current month, e.g. "October"
- Cell A2 - contains the value of the current year, e.g. "2014"
- Cell A3 - contains the value of a given day, e.g "22"

I'd like to populate A3 with a formula that will give it the value 22 October 2014 and have this formatted as a date so I can perform comparisons and calculations in other cells - so along the lines of `22` + `A1` + `A2`. I've tried using the `CONCATENATE` function but this doesn't let me format the cell as a date.

Is something like this even possible using the standard Excel functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `DATEVALUE` function. It can convert month names into a numerical date expression, which you can then format as a date (`dd/mm/yyyy` in the example below).

```
=DATEVALUE(A3 & " " & A1 & " " & A2)
```

[image]

As a bonus, this will also work if A1 contains short-form month names i.e. Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.

I just did a bit of testing, which showed that you can also drop the `" "` space delimiters entirely:

```
=DATEVALUE(A3&A1&A2)
```

In fact, just using `--` to force Excel to treat the concatenated string as a numerical value works as well!

```
=--(A3&A1&A2)
```

So far, my testing has not found any instance where `--` doesn't work as well as `DATEVALUE`. Leaves me wondering what the point of `DATEVALUE` is.

Comment: I think this approach will depend heavily on regional settings?

Comment: Do you mean, if month names are entered in a different language than the regional settings? Yeah, that's true. Is it relevant? Depends on the OP's application.

Comment: Thanks both. For info, my application is only applicable to a single region therefore this solution will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`=DATE(A2,MATCH(A1,{"January","February","March","April","May","June",
"July","August","September","October","November","December"},0),A3)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this formula

`=(A1&A2)+A3-1`

format result cell in required date format